# Store the number of times a popup has been clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup, bootstrap-modal

Following is my Bootstrap modal code, which is generated dynamically inside a loop. I have a unique ID for each one. Each popup stores post details. I would like to store and display the number of times the popup has been clicked. The ID has to be the ID generated dynamically (). Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content custmmodal">
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icofont-close-circled"></i></button>

          <?php
            $postId = get_the_ID();
            $post = get_post($postId); //assuming $id has been initialized
            setup_postdata($post);
            ?>
          <div class="postimg"> <?php if(has_post_video( $postId )){?>
                                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[featured-video-plus]'); ?>
                                    <?php }else {?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($postId) );  ?>">
                                    
                                    <?php } ?></div>
          <div class="postinfo">
                <div class="pstadmin">
                  <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                  <div class="date"> <?php the_time('j M,Y'); ?></div>
                  <p><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
                    
                </div>
              <div class="reactncunt text-left">
              <?php echo do_shortcode('[reactions count=true button=false]');?>
              </div>
              <div class="reaction">
                  <div class="reacbtns">
                      <?php 
                                                 if(is_user_logged_in()){ 
                                ?>                   
                                   <a class="lrm-login " href="#"><?php echo do_shortcode('[reactions count=false button=true]');?></a>                 

                                                <?php }else{?>
                                                <a class="lrm-login wtutlginimg" href="#">
                                                    <div class="dw-reactions-button">
                                                        <div class="dw-reactions-box">
                                                            <span class="dw-reaction dw-reaction-like"><strong>Like</strong></span>
                                                            <span class="dw-reaction dw-reaction-love"><strong>Love</strong></span>
                                                            <span class="dw-reaction dw-reaction-angry"><strong>Clap</strong></span>
                                                        </div> 
                                                    </div>
                      </a>   
                                            <?php    }?>
                      <!--<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="comntbtn"><i class="icofont-comment"></i> Comment</a>-->
                      <div class="shearbtn">
                          <?php 
                          if(is_user_logged_in()){ 

                              echo do_shortcode('[addtoany]');

                          }else{?>
                          <a class="lrm-login" href="#"><img class="shrimg" src="<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/share.png"></a>
                          <?php }?>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>


              </div>
              
                
              <?php comments_template(); ?>  
              
<!--                 <div class="imginfo">
            <div class="counting">
             
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            
          </div> -->
              </div>


          <?php  wp_reset_postdata();
?>  
            
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        

      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what you have tried to achieve above ?

Comment: I want to keep a track of how many time the popup is clicked. The popup is getting generated dynamically in a loop. I want to keep track of each one.